# How to display image when it select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

As show Below image. 
I have 4 images. when user click on any image that image display at purple dot. when click second time it display at pink dot.
and also remove when i click on it[image]

For Example :-

First i click on 1st image so it display at purple dot.
Then
I click on 4th image so it display at pink dot.

[image]

Comment: post your code, show you effort.

Comment: First of all , need to know if those images will just be plain background with numbers on it. If so then why images, why can't you use divs with background colors. Please clarify if those images will be real images

Comment: @arunbahal this image i take for only example image. atuly i build online ordering website.  so when user select "subji" that particular "subji" display here.

Comment: okay then , for each image you should have thumbnails and once you click on any image, you can add class "Active" and place that corresponding thumbnail on top of tray image and once you click again you need to check if that image has class "active" if yes, then remove that class and remove the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, you have to use javascript for this.
have 2 elements that are display hidden (the purple and the pink dot)
then the 4 images with all the same class.
In the js file put someting like this

```
$( ".image" ).click(function() {
  $( "#purpledot" ).css({
    display: 'block'
  });
});
```

and for the purple dot

```
$( ".dotclass" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).css({
        display: 'none'
  });
});
```